# How to detect classname with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to click on an element and then depending on whether it has a specific class name, do something.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="my-class" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  if (element.classList.contains("my-class")) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: div class="my-class"

Comment: Is it React or do you want to write `class`, not `classname`?

Comment: Also, what is `element` where do you declare it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I meant class not classname. It is written as class in my code I just wrote the wrong thing here because I'm used to react.

Comment: `element` does not get set in your code. Use `function myFunction ( eve ) {
  if (eve.target.classList.contains ....`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the click event then get the target element which in this case is the clicked element.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("my-class")) {
    alert("I Do things becuase i have (my-class)")
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="my-class" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction(event)">I Do nothing</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @collapsar mentioned in comment, `element` is't set. I recommand you to use `addEventListener` and `event.target`.

```js
document.getElementById("your-element").addEventListener("click", () =>{
  if (event.target.classList.contains("my-class")) {
    console.log("your-element has \"my-class\" class")
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="your-element" class="my-class">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the HTML element rendered statically you should consider two things:

1. Wait for the DOM ready event in order to make modifications on the element.
2. Attach the event dynamically, making sure that you bind the event handler to new elements after adding them to the DOM.

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-class" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  if (element.classList.contains("my-class")) {
    //do something
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // DOM is ready
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  }
});
```